# How to get the button id dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

hi guys i am trying to get a button id that is in a for loop so whenever the button click the unique id that can be differentiated from other ids should be able to work. let me show you my code.

```
 <?php foreach ($message as $key ) : ?>
                                    <?php echo $senders_user_id=$key['senders_id']; ?>
                                    <div class="senders_id"  S_id="<?php echo $key['senders_id']; ?>" style="display: none;"></div>
                            <a  class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                             <?php echo form_open(,['id'=>'sender_user_id']); ?>
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <button id="senders_id" class="Read" S_id="<?php echo $key['senders_id'];?>" onclick="readbyuser($senders_user_id);">Read</button>
                                <button  id="senders_id" class="unread"  S_id="<?php echo $key['senders_id'];?>" onclick="unreadbyuser($senders_user_id);">Unread</button> 

                            </label>
                            </div>           

                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="name" style="min-width: 120px;
                            display: inline-block;"><?php echo $key['uname']; ?></span> <span class=""><?php echo $key['textdata']; ?></span>
                        <span class="text-muted" style="font-size: 11px;"></span> <span class="badge">12:10 AM</span> <span class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip">
                        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                            </span></span></a>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
```

Now here there are three post meaning three 'senders_id' so when i click on button Read the id of that should pass but the same id is passing again and again no matter which button i click on

Here is my code

```
function readbyuser()
{
    var senders_id=$('#senders_id').attr('S_id');
    var Recievers_id=$('.Recievers_id').attr('R_id');
jQuery.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'<?php echo base_url("user/read_by_user"); ?>',
            data:{id:senders_id,R_id:Recievers_id},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);

                alert(data);

                $('.unread').removeClass('unread_user');
                $('.Read').addClass('read_user');


            }


        });

}
function unreadbyuser()
{
var senders_id=$('#senders_id').attr('S_id');
    var Recievers_id=$('.Recievers_id').attr('R_id');
jQuery.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'<?php echo base_url("user/unread_by_user"); ?>',
            data:{id:senders_id,R_id:Recievers_id},
           dataType:'json',

            success:function(data)
            {



  $('.Read').removeClass('read_user');
    $('.unread').addClass('unread_user');
    }
});
}
```

please tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: Please clean this up and provide us with a direct question. No one will sort through this mess of code for you.

Comment: Make an effort to provide a minimal example. People steer clear of walls of code that is mostly unrelated to the question. Is including the commented code necessary here? If not why would it be in the question?

Comment: Agree with both @BlakeConnally and apokryfos , Unfortunately folks still don't read the guidelines of posting the question. But are we gonna help him or down vote him because the question is not properly formatted?

Comment: hi, do you want similar like this? `http://jsbin.com/zuzusiz/3/edit?html,output` . i create this to simplify your code. if yes, i'll be try to advanced that sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="senders_id" class="Read" S_id="<?php echo $key['senders_id'];?>" onclick="readbyuser($senders_user_id);">Read</button>


<button  id="senders_id" class="unread"  S_id="<?php echo $key['senders_id'];?>" onclick="unreadbyuser($senders_user_id);">Unread</button>
```

Two elements cannot have samei id. Use class name instead.

Also you can pass PHP values directly in this.

`onclick="readbyuser($senders_user_id);"`

as

`onclick="readbyuser(<?php echo $key['senders_id'];?>);"`

Comment: but the ajax result that i want is showing on all the buttons even when i click the button with id=3 the button with id=9 would get its color changed @Akshay Praksh